# Connection exception from SqlCeDataAdapter.fill()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Following numerous examples here and on MSDN, I can't figure out why I'm encountering an exception on adapter.Fill() below, nor do I understand why the exception is not caught here in the try{...} catch() clock, but rather in Program.Main().

The exception is

```
"-      $exception  {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}   System.Exception {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException}
```

and the inner exception is

```
        _message    "ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized."  string
```

What on earth am I missing here? Connection not initialized? I just opened it!

```
    private static SqlCeConnection _cnxn = null;
    public static SqlCeConnection cnxn
    {
        get
        {
            if (_cnxn == null)
            {
                _cnxn = new SqlCeConnection(global::Format_Generator_15.Properties.Settings.Default.FGConnectionString);
            }
            return _cnxn;
        }
    }

    private static DataTable inputTable = null;
    public static DataTable InputTable
    {
        get
        {
            if (inputTable == null)
            {
                if (cnxn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    cnxn.Open();
                try
                {
                    SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from input", cnxn);
                    inputTable = new DataTable();

                    adapter.Fill(inputTable);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't get the input table. " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            return inputTable;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged to see if the connection string is properly initialized?

Comment: Don't use properties like they're methods. The expectation with properties is that they contain minimal logic and can be safely accessed multiple times in a row. Also, use `using` blocks to dispose of your IDisposables (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, etc)

Comment: @Ric, I was stepping through in the debugger and the connection is open and was previously used to create and populate the table it's trying to access.

Comment: @DanielMann, I don't understand what you mean about using properties like methods. The way I use the lazily instantiated connection member is not unorthodox, is it? If I were to wrap any of this with using(...), wouldn't it be disposed/invalid by the time it returns the DataTable to the caller?

Comment: False alarm. It turns out the error was somewhere else and unrelated to the code above.